# Why is it necessary to call rng() twice in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random

This seems like a bug to me. It seems like it is necessary to call `rng()` twice in Matlab to get the desired seeding. Consider the following experiments:

```
>> sd = rng(3) % THIS DOES NOT WORK

sd = 

     Type: 'twister'
     Seed: 0
    State: [625x1 uint32]

>> sd = rng(3) % BUT NOW IT DOES

sd = 

     Type: 'twister'
     Seed: 3
    State: [625x1 uint32]

>> sd = rng(3) % AND AGAIN, TO CONFIRM

sd = 

     Type: 'twister'
     Seed: 3
    State: [625x1 uint32]

>> sd = rng('shuffle') % BUT THIS FAILS

sd = 

     Type: 'twister'
     Seed: 3
    State: [625x1 uint32]

>> sd = rng('shuffle') % BUT ON THE SECOND GO IT WORKS

sd = 

     Type: 'twister'
     Seed: 87326715
    State: [625x1 uint32]

>> sd = rng('shuffle') % AND ON THE THIRD

sd = 

     Type: 'twister'
     Seed: 87326802
    State: [625x1 uint32]

>> sd = rng(4) % BUT AGAIN THIS FAILS

sd = 

     Type: 'twister'
     Seed: 87326987
    State: [625x1 uint32]

>> sd = rng(4) % BUT ON THE SECOND GO IT WORKS AGAIN

sd = 

     Type: 'twister'
     Seed: 4
    State: [625x1 uint32]

>> sd = rng(4) % AND SO ON

sd = 

     Type: 'twister'
     Seed: 4
    State: [625x1 uint32]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:**
 According to the documentation, the return value of `rng` is *previous* state:

> sprev = rng(...) returns the previous settings of the random number
>   generator used by rand, randi,and randn before changing the settings.

So, the answer is: *no, it is not a bug*. The random number generator was correctly initialized the first time you called it.

However, it is quite an unexpected behavior, in my opinion.

---

**A bit longer answer:**
I suggest using `RandStream` objects instead, which are much more easy to comprehend for anyone with basic knowledge in object oriented programming. For instance:

```
s1 = RandStream.create('mrg32k3a');
r1 = rand(s1,100000,1);
```

I strongly suggest to avoid setting the global stream, as it has all of the disadvantages of global variables.

```
%Not recommended! (Due to global variable)
s = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',1);
RandStream.setGlobalStream(s);
```

**Edit (1)** 
I would like to explain my opinion about why setting the global random number generator is not a good practice. Basically, the purpose of any good software is to reduce the scope of any variable, in order to [reduce coupling and increase cohesion](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse403/96sp/coupling-cohesion.html). Global variable has the highest possible coupling (any routine may use it) and lowest possible cohesion. Global random number generator is even **more** risky than a normal variable, because it has much more chances to be used by someone else.

Re-seeding the global random number generator might lead to some bizarre errors. Consider the following example - you are writing a program that runs in `for` loop and generates a random number.

```
 for i=1:N
     k = randn(1,1); 
     %... Do something
 end
```

Everything seems to be perfect. Now you want to add a third party function `Foo` in the middle of your loop that does some stuff. The designer of the code decided to re-seed the global number generator to `1`.

```
 for i=1:N
     k = randn(1,1); 
     %... Do something
     Foo();
 end

 function Foo()
     %Do some stuff
     rng(1);
 end
```

Surprise! Now your program generates a completely non-random sequence of numbers, namely, exactly the same number in each loop call.

Some more reading data, if you're still not convinced - [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29), [here](http://sce2.umkc.edu/csee/mullinsj/it350/lectures/7.Coupling-cohesion.pdf) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: Ugh, you're right. Also, it's very unexpected. For example, consider this behaviour. Here `sd.Seed` is 3: `rng(3); sd=rng()`. But here, `sd.Seed` will be whatever it was before: `sd = rng(3)`

Comment: @Andrey, I can hear the developers crying as they read your answer. The `rng` command was introduced as a _simplification_ of the `RandStream` functionality, which was deliberately designed to be a little arcane (what's "mrg32k3a"?) in order to discourage users from meddling with the internals of random number streams unless they knew exactly what they were doing. And here you are, saying that `rng` is confusing but `RandStream` is easy to comprehend. No criticism of you - but the gap between your expectations and the design is ironic.

Comment: What? That's a strange objection to the globalstream. If one doesn't want to use it, it would not be because of the usual objections to global variables. Also, the OP's question is about `rng`, which is based on the globalstream by default.

Comment: @SamRoberts, horchler thanks for your comment! You're right that it was introduced as simplification. The thing is that Matlab is being used by a lot of users who have no knowledge in software engineering or OOP, for them the concept of objects was difficult to comprehend. About global random number generator, I will try to expand my answer to explain what I meant.

Comment: @horchler, Thanks for your comment. I've added a section that clarifies about global variables.

Comment: @Andrey: You're gone off on a tangent far beyond the OP's question, which is not about writing third party software. There's a perfectly valid use case for `rng` for many users. I just think it would be more helpful, if you're going beyond the user's original question, to clarify how `rng` should be properly used rather than claiming that it's a bad idea to use it at all. FYI, I write a toolbox that uses `RandStream` objects. I still use `rng` all over the place in my own scripts because it's convenient and readable code.

Comment: The return of the old state by `rng` is intended to allow people to be able to set the state using `rng`, and then safely revert it using a pattern like so: `oldState = rng(desiredState); x = onCleanup(@()rng(oldState)); doStuffWithRngInDesiredState();`

Comment: Thanks @Edric. That pattern of usage that you suggested will definitely reduce errors like I've described.